# Find supremum and infimum of $A=\left\lbrace\frac{2013}{1+\epsilon+\epsilon^{-1}}:\epsilon\in(0,1)\right\rbrace$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Find $\sup{A},\inf{A},\max{A},\min{A}$ where:
$$A=\left\lbrace\frac{2013}{1+\epsilon+\epsilon^{-1}}:\epsilon\in(0,1)\right\rbrace$$

I suspect that $\sup{A}=\frac{2013}{3}, \inf{A}=0$ and max and min don't exist, I can easily prove that my candidates are upper and lower bounds, but how to proceed from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. You can prove it by using that $A$ is strictly increasing in $\epsilon$, in the interval $(0,1)$ since $$\frac{∂A}{∂\epsilon}=−2013\frac{\epsilon^2-1}{\epsilon^4+2\epsilon^3+3\epsilon^2+2\epsilon+1}>0, \qquad \forall\epsilon\in(0,1)$$

Comment: I'm not allowed to use derivatives. Also why can I say that $\frac{2013}{3}$ is the sup I'm looking for knowing only that the function is strictly increasing on a given interval?

Comment: @qiubit: What are you allowed to use?

Comment: Only the definition of sup and inf. I can also use limits but only for sequences not functions